# Bootstrap form validator

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Bootstrap 3. I am creating a login page and I have this code:
* I got this generated from Bootply.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Registry Login</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input_email">Email</label>  
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <input id="input_username" name="input_email" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="email">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Password input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input_password">Password</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="input_password" name="input_password" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="password">

  </div>
</div>


<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="" name="" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

I keyed in on my Email field this sample string `abcde` and I received a small tooltip saying that `Please enter an email address`. Is there a way for me to change the text?

Comment: what are you using the backend? If you need client-side validation for email format, you will have to do that through jquery.

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter with Bootstrap 3. I just noticed that there is built in validator that do this, so I want to maximize it by changing the text it returns.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the form options with Codeigniter, I'm not too familiar with it, but it sounds like it would be under a submit code for a post.